# pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'lock' object while logging in closure(function) with mapPartitions

Tags: python, logging, pyspark

Uncommenting the _log.info(e) works fine. With _log.info(e) raises the Pickling Error: Can't pickle lock object

```
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def write_tsdb(partition):
   count = 0
   failed_count = 0
   for value in partition:
      try:
        //write to tsdb
        count += 1
      except Exception, e:
         **_log.info(e)**
         print e
         failed_count += 1
         continue
   return count, failed_count 

def main():
      logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

      details = left outer join(rdd1) & (rdd2)
      tsdb_count = details.mapPartitions(write_tsdb)
      print tsdb_count.take(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

**What to do?**

One of handlers that installed on parent (root) logger have a `Lock` object. If logging is must-have in this function, consider replacing `_log.info(e)` with `logging.getLogger(__name__).info(e)`.

**Details**

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` adds `StreamHandler` for root logger. `StreamHandler` is inherited from `Handler` that creates one `Lock` object per instance. [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/**init**.py#L773](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L773)

It is easy to reproduce. This raises an exception.

```
import pickle, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
pickle.dumps(log)
```

And this doesn't:

```
import pickle, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.getLogger().handlers = []  # Remove handlers from root logger
pickle.dumps(log)
```

That said, loggers are quite useless without handlers. To avoid the pickling err we can create a function that is picklable and use it to get log object (could be a property on a class) or create log object in every function that has to be picklable.

Answer (score -2):

Your `except Exception, e:` is wrong.

It should read: `except Exception as e:`

It is possible that somewhere you defined a value for an `e` variable (some `Lock`?) and here you, by accident, try to log it, mistakenly thinking it is an exception.